# opencv_core244d.dll appears to be missing from computer

Tags: opencv

Hey there I followed the installation guide of OpenCV 2.4.4 on Windows 7 here http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cgo0UitHfp8
And I linked all system path variables to their respective directories. I also followed all his steps of including the libraries in the linker and C/C++ properties, but I used vc11 instead of vc10 (he's using opencv 2.4.3). And I was able to build the project just fine, it knows where the libraries are. But once I run it a window pops up with the following error message "opencv_core244d.dll is missing from your computer". It can't seem to find the .dll files even though I'm pointing to the right directories. Any suggestions?

EDIT: I read online that this sort of thing can happen if the .dll files are not in the same project directory. So I added the dll files and then go the following message when attempting to run :"MSVCP100.dll is missing from your computer"

I'm no expert when it comes to dll files. This is my first time using Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*.lib file is used to build, and *.dll file whose name is same with the lib file is used to run your program. So, runtime path will be used to find your dll files.
 Try to edit your system %PATH% variable(add your-opencv-dir/build/your-platform/vc11/*bin* to your %PATH%) and restart visual studio.

Comment: I'm going to try it on my own Windows installation instead of the school's computer and see what happens. I thought I followed all steps correctly, guess not. Thanks though!

Comment: restart Visual Studio or add dlls inside your debug folder

Answer (score 0):

missing .lib files are for the linker at build time.
missing .dll files just put them with the compiled program.

Then it works fine because I have just done it.

The dll files are in the bin directory the lib files are in the lib directory.
Couple of other points, 2 types of lib file one with a d or not depends on what build you are doing debug or release. The linker dependencies flag needs to be changed from NO to YES on VS 2013. Other than that it is just paths to find files.